# How to sort groups and children Expandable listview in Android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have two tables in mysql which bind 'Categories' and 'products' through ids 'id_catprods' and 'ID_Cat'. So far so good, I'm working on Android with "ExpandableListView" with a custom adapter and everything works fine but can not find the solution to sort the categories with their products. Can anyone help me?

Json results:

```
{
"productos": [{
    "id_catprods": "1",
    "id_oferta": "197",
    "id_producto": "1",
    "nombr_cat": "Bocatas",
    "id_cat": "1",
    "nombre_producto": "Lomo",
    "precio": "4",
    "actions": []
}, {
    "id_catprods": "2",
    "id_oferta": "197",
    "id_producto": "2",
    "nombr_cat": "Pizzas",
    "id_cat": "2",
    "nombre_producto": "Serranito",
    "precio": "4",
    "actions": []
}],
"errorCode": 0,
"errorString": "Todo correcto"
}
```

Main code:

```
// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            String givemeurl;

            public DownloadJSON(String url) {
                this.givemeurl = id_oferta;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Category.this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://file.php");

                if(jsonobject != null){         
                    try {
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("productos");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects
                            map.put("nombr_cat", jsonobject.getString("nombr_cat"));
                            map.put("nombre_producto", jsonobject.getString("nombre_producto"));
                            map.put("id_cat", jsonobject.getString("id_cat"));
                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());         
                    }
                }else{
                    //Log.e("Response","No data");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                ExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

                /*if(listview.getCount() == 0){
                    listview.setVisibility(View.GONE); // ERROR A CORREGIR, DOBLE CAPA?
                    listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(givemeempty));
                    TextView bottom = new TextView(Category.this);
                    bottom.setHeight(50); //50dp
                    bottom.setText("");
                    // Adding bottom
                    listview.addFooterView(bottom);
                }else{
                }*/
                adapter = new ListViewAdapterCat(Category.this, arraylist);
                ExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Code of Adapter:

```
 public class ListViewAdapterCat extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapterCat(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;    
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3,
            ViewGroup arg4) {   
        TextView tv = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
            System.out.println(data.get(i).get("id_cat"));
            if(data.get(i).get("id_cat").equals("1")){
                tv.setText(resultp.get(Category.nombre_producto));
            }else if (data.get(i).get("id_cat").equals("2")){
                tv.setText(resultp.get(Category.nombre_producto));
            }else if (data.get(i).get("id_cat").equals("3")){
                tv.setText(resultp.get(Category.nombre_producto));
            }

        }
        return tv;
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }
    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int arg3, boolean arg1, View convertView, ViewGroup arg4) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.nombr_cat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombree);
            Log.e("ID DEL GRUPO", ""+arg3);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        resultp = data.get(arg3);

        holder.nombr_cat.setText(resultp.get(Category.nombr_cat));
        holder.nombr_cat.setTextSize(20);
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView nombr_cat;
        public TextView nombre_producto;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sort them when querying in MySql if possible. Otherwise, here is one suggestion. Store the categories in a `ArrayList<String>`. You can easily sort them using one of `Collection.sort()`. Then, store your products in a `Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Product>>` where the key is the category name and the data is a Product class that stores your product details. You can sort your Product class using an `Comparator<Product>`. You will need to modify the adapter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Collections.sort(arraylist);
```

or

```
list.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

This will sort your arraylist and If you have Expandable list you have to use

```
        Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<Modelclass>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Modelclass o1, Modelclass o2) {

                Collections.sort(o1.getsubarraylist(), new Comparator<Modelclass>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Modelclass o1, Modelclass o2) {
                    return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
                       }
                    });

               Collections.sort(o2.getsubarraylist(), new Comparator<Modelclass>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Modelclass o1, Modelclass o2) {
                    return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
                       }
                    });

             return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName()); 
// *This Sorts The Group's if you don't wanna sort group simply return 0*;
          }
        });
```

**NOTE:- o1.getsubarraylist() & o2.getsubarraylist() is Child list's of a expandable list, Just add inner Collections.sort() for sorting expandable list's**

or if you have Simple **String** arraylist

```
         Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
             return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
              }
           });
```

*I hope this helps someone in need....*

Answer (score -1):

Better and easy way to sort **Categories** with **product** is from `mysql` query. You can use `inner join` or any other which fits on your case to sort and make relation between **products** and **categories**.

Comment: I'm currently using Inner Join. $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM (catprods INNER JOIN productos ON catprods.id_producto=productos.id_cat) WHERE id_oferta = '$id_oferta'"); What would you change in the query?

Comment: use `id_cat` as foreign key in `productos`, and inner join like this `catprods INNER JOIN productos ON catprods.id_cat=productos.id_cat` and use `order by` for sorting