# How to Sort json Object key in sequence order?

Tags: android, json

Here is my json structure

```
{
  "menus": [
    {
      "sequence":"1",
      "Name":"Sector"
    },
    {
      "sequence":"3",
      "Name":"Segment"
    },
    {
      "sequence":"2",
      "Name":"Collection"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to parse/storing data like 1,2,3 in sequence order?

Comment: where is data coming from ?

Comment: The json data coming from server. I want to show menu which is they mentioned in sequence order.

Comment: Store them in ArrayList<Object> and sort the list.

Comment: ask server guy to send the in sorted order that will help for all client like android, iOS and your sorting code remains in a single place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370225/how-to-sort-groups-and-children-expandable-listview-in-android/40546048#40546048

Answer (score 1):

Parse your array in a list

```
JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

then use collection.sort to sort the newly created list

```
Collections.sort( jsonList, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

    public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
        String valA = new String();
        String valB = new String();

        try {
            valA = (String) a.get("sequence");
            valB = (String) b.get("sequence");
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //do something
        }

        return valA.compareTo(valB);
    }
});
```

Insert the sorted values in your array

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    sortedJsonArray.put(jsonList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: this is so wrong, you should compare numeric values, not strings - this will sort it like 1,10,100,2,20,200 etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Object class & initiate  variable's,like bellow & apply getter & setter like below.

class Menus
{

private String sequence;

private String Name;

public String getSequence() 
  {

```
 return sequence;
```

}

public void setSequence(String sequence) 
   {

```
    this.sequence= sequence;

}
```

public String getName() 
   {

```
    return name;

}
```

public void setName(String name) 
    {

```
    this.Name= name;

}
```

}

2.Then parse your Json Values like bellow

3. Intitiate the list as Menus list;

List menuslist = new ArrayList();

try{

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.toString);

JSONArray array =jObject.getJSONArray("menus");

for(int i=0; i

JSONObject Object = array.JSONObject(i);

Menus menus = new Menus();

menus.setSequence(Object.getString("sequence"));

menus.setName(Object.getString("name"));

menuslist.add(menus);

}

}

catch(JSONException Je)
  {

je.printexception;

}

Answer (score 0):

I did using TreeMap.

```
Map sequenceMenuOrder = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                                    int position = 0;
                                    for (int index = 0; index < menus.length(); index++) {
                                        sequenceMenuOrder.put(menus.getJSONObject(index).getString("sequence"), menus.getJSONObject(index).getString("menuName"));
                                    }
                                    for (Object value : sequenceMenuOrder.keySet()) {
                                        if (position != 0) {
                                            menuString += ",";
                                        }
                                        menuString += sequenceMenuOrder.get(value);
                                        position++;
                                    }
```